# Find least used icons/files/folders on desktop in windows

Tags: java, windows, file, find, desktop

I have an assignment to find least used icons on desktop in Windows.
I need to code using JAVA. Which property of the File object in JAVA will be useful?
I have started analysis on it. A help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post what you have tried already, others are more likely to help if you show you have started to work on it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the File API? [`File#lastAccessTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#lastAccessTime%28%29) is probably what you are looking for. Keep in mind that this only works in Java 7.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I think the lastAccessTime will provide only the last access time. What about all previous accesses of the file?

Comment: @Vivek Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html). It may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

As for FREQUENCY of use, I do not think Windows keeps any data per-file...  So you will have to rely on the last time of modification, possibly vs time of creation.  The Java function you will need to rely on is lastModified(), eg

```
file_list[i].lastModified()
```

Comment: Modification only tells you when the file was last modified, not when it was last used (accessed).

Comment: OH... yeah.  Try this library: http://www.javaxt.com/   and try the function getLastAccessTime()